# How to Set Root Directory in Apache Mina Sshd Server in Java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, apache-mina

I use **Apache Mina Sshd API** to start up a local SFTP server in java.In SFTP client i use **Jcraft jsch API** to create my SFTP client.I successfully start up a server.The problem is that i want to write some unit test cases to check whether client can put some files into server's root directory. Currently my SFTP server doesn't have any root directory.So i would like to know that is there is any approach to set server's root directory.

Eg: **C:\sftp**  How can i set this path as my server root directory.so then client can read and write files to it every time connect with the server.Thank you.

```
public class SftpServerStarter {

    private SshServer sshd;
    private final static Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpServerStarter.class);

    public void start(){
        sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(22);
        sshd.setHost("localhost");
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new MyPasswordAuthenticator());
        sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new MyPublickeyAuthenticator());
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
        sshd.setSubsystemFactories(
            Arrays.<NamedFactory<Command>>asList(new SftpSubsystem.Factory()));
        sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());

        try {
            logger.info("Starting ...");
            sshd.start();
            logger.info("Started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Can not Start Server");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start sftp server programmatically in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531342/how-to-start-sftp-server-programmatically-in-java)

Comment: @DanielNewtown Hi mate, I know this is a long while back.. could you please re-post that article in the link? it returns a 404 now as we speak. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Default it takes the root path from System property called `user.dir`

Inorder to change this, you can override `getVirtualUserDir()` in `NativeFileSystemView` and return your path.

```
    sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new NativeFileSystemFactory() {
        @Override
        public FileSystemView createFileSystemView(final Session session) {
            return new NativeFileSystemView(session.getUsername(), false) {
                @Override
                public String getVirtualUserDir() {
                    return  "C:\\MyRoot";
                }
            };
        };
    });
```

Comment: Hi Tharaka,
I am working on the same type of use case now, but i want to create a totally virtual file system for the user when he logs in using winscp or any other sftp client. I am trying to create or set the root directory for the user such as "/xyz" and the sub directories such as "/abc" instead of any system file directory (eg: "C:\"). Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 11):

In more recent sshd versions you can use `org.apache.sshd.common.file.virtualfs.VirtualFileSystemFactory` and supply it to the `SshServer` instance via method `setFileSystemFactory`.

Snippet:

```
VirtualFileSystemFactory fileSystemFactory = new VirtualFileSystemFactory();
fileSystemFactory.setDefaultHomeDir("home.directory");
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(fileSystemFactory)
```

Comment: This now requires a Path object, e.g.:

fileSystemFactory.setDefaultHomeDir(Files.createTempDirectory("sshd_"))

Answer (score 3):

You can also follow following link to know about how to set root directory in Apache Mina sshd SFTP server with different **sshd-core** version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

into

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[How to override getVirtualUserDir() in Apache Mina sshd-core version 0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789995/how-to-override-getvirtualuserdir-in-apache-mina-sshd-core-version-0-14-0?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the only solution available for 0.14.0 version of sshd-core.