# How to access Apache Mina sshd sftp server from remote machine

Tags: java, localhost, sftp, apache-mina

I start up sftp server using Apache Mina Sshd Api. please refer follow link to see more details about my local SFTP server.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389249/how-to-set-root-directory-in-apache-mina-sshd-server-in-java).

I tried to connect to that server from remotely by giving host name as my ip address but i couldn't enable to connect with the sftp server. I got "**connection refused**" error message.But i can connect locally.To connect locally i use  **[winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)** sftp client giving my host name as "localhost" but in remotely i can not give host name as localhost.So i gave host name as my machine IP address.When i gave that i got above error message.

So i would like to know that how can i connect with my local sftp server from remote machine.

Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What specifically happens when you try to connect to your SFTP server? Do you get any error messages? What do they say? What address and TCP port is your SFTP server set to listen for connections on? Could you run netstat and verify that the SFTP server is listening for connections? Please edit your question to include all of this information.

Comment: Thanks Kenster for your feed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally found out **How to access Apache Mina sshd sftp server from remote machine**. The problem was on my Apache Mina sshd sftp server set up.You can refer attached [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389249/how-to-set-root-directory-in-apache-mina-sshd-server-in-java) to see my Apache Mina sshd sftp server details.

In there previously i set host as `sshd.setHost("localhost");` instead of that i changed it into `sshd.setHost(0.0.0.0);`.So now you can access your local sftp server providing your machine ip address as a host name from remote machine.