# How to override getVirtualUserDir() in Apache Mina sshd-core version 0.14.0

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina

I used Apache Mina sshd-core version 0.10.0.Due to some issues with file uploading i had to change version into 0.14.0.In there i can not override getVirtualUserDir() method. Below is my sample code,

```
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new NativeFileSystemFactory() {
        @Override
        public FileSystemView createFileSystemView(final Session session) {
            return new NativeFileSystemView(session.getUsername(), false) {
                @Override
                public String getVirtualUserDir() {

                    return "C:/root";
                }
            };
        };
    });
```

I would like to know that how can i overcome that problem in Apache Mina sshd-core version 0.14.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the `getVirtualUserDir` in Mina SSHD 0.10.0 was to set an initial directory of the file system.

In Mina SSHD 0.14.0 the same purpose is served by `current` parameter of `NativeFileSystemView` constructor:

```
public NativeFileSystemView(String userName, Map<String, String> roots, String current)
```

Note that the documentation claims not to call the constructor directly and use `NativeFileSystemFactory` instead. But the `NativeFileSystemFactory` never calls that overload of the constructor. Either the comment is obsolete or the factory is not finished yet.

Or it's a typo and it should have actually referred to `VirtualFileSystemFactory`. What is the factory you probably should use instead of overriding `NativeFileSystemFactory`.

```
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory("C:/root"));
```

Comment: You save my time buddy.