# Apache Mina SSHD 1.0.0 set user directory & mapping

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, sshd, mina

Trying to set a home directory for a user using Apache Mina SSHD embedded in Java.

Both solutions are deprecated in 1.0 in-
[How to Set Root Directory in Apache Mina Sshd Server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389249)
[How to override getVirtualUserDir() in Apache Mina sshd-core version 0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789995)

In 0.14.0 the following worked fine:

```
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new NativeFileSystemFactory() {
   @Override
   public FileSystemView createFileSystem(final Session session) {
      HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
      map.put("/", "/Users/someone/Documents");
      return new NativeFileSystemView(session.getUsername(), map, "/");
   };
});
```

This is as far as I got:

```
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new NativeFileSystemFactory() {
    @Override
    public FileSystem createFileSystem(Session session) {
        // What should I do here?
        return super.createFileSystem(session);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.
I had to use the `VirtualFileSystemFactory` *class*.

This is the result:

```
VirtualFileSystemFactory fsFactory = new VirtualFileSystemFactory();
fsFactory.setUserHomeDir(userName, realDirectory);
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(fsFactory);
```

Note:
If you're using *OS X* or *linux*, don't forget to `chmod` your path first.

Answer (score 0):

For v1.2.0 (if Java 7) / v1.3.0 (if Java 8) and *java.nio.file.Path* usage, the solution could be :

```
sshServer.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(rootDir)));
```